# How can I Disable session files from being created in "_private/session" directory?

Tags: php, session, ini

My site has a "_private/session" folder which seems to be creating a file for each session and then keeping the file causing my hosting plan to be in violation due to more than 1,024 inodes.

The site is being hosted on GoDaddy... I know what you're going to say... don't host on GoDaddy.  However, I would appreciate help and constructive input.

The limit is 1,024 inodes (files and folders) per directory.  The _private/session directory already has over 2,200 files so far today and it's not even 9:00 am.  Is this a server thing?  The code was developed by someone that no longer works with us so I am left with the pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEFORE I POSTED THIS QUESTION... I looked at the variables in the php.ini file and noticed that there are many options for the session saves.  For instance, there is a variable for the lifespan (length in time that a session is alive for).  Mine was set way too high.  There is also a variable for the frequency that the "garbage collector" runs.  This was set to 1/1000 which meant that there was a .1% chance that the garbage would be cleaned out when a new session begins.  I set mine to 1/20 which means it will be cleaned out a lot more.  additionally, there are options to change the folder that these files are saved in, an option to make sub directories, an option to change the file names and so much more.  So glad I looked at this before I posted my question.  Hope this helps someone else!